# Can't serialize form

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, contacts

Was just trying to make serialization results be visible in some 'results' div. Used the code like this from JQUERy learning center for the contact form:

```
function showValues() {
      var str = $("form").serialize();
      $("#result").text( str );
      }
     showValues();
```

But that did not work. No serialized content in the div. I saved everything on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3tKUh/1/

There is not any final code. I just would like to know why serialization results are not displayed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a serialized form, you have to add a name attribut to your input field like this (http://jsfiddle.net/3tKUh/2/) :

```
<form id="myform">
<div class="field">
<label for="name" id="namelabel">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="req" autofocus>
</div>
<div class="error" id="name_error">
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="req">
</div>
<div class="error" id="email_error">
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="message" name="message" id="message">Message</label>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="field">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="send">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks that helped. couldn't find anything on that. Please if you can provide me with a link to read on this matter. thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ have a look to the examples. You can see fiels have a name attribute. And if my answer could help you, validate my answer.